# Error while using Python 3 to mask existing data using Faker

Tags: python-3.x, faker, data-masking

I am using Python 3 to mask a dataset using Faker package. I obtained a code available at: 
http://blog.districtdatalabs.com/a-practical-guide-to-anonymizing-datasets-with-python-faker.

Code:

```
def anonymize_rows(rows):

"""
Rows is an iterable of dictionaries that contain name and
email fields that need to be anonymized.
"""
    # Load the faker and its providers
    faker  = Factory.create()

    # Create mappings of names & emails to faked names & emails.
    c1  = defaultdict(faker.CARD_NO_ID)
    c2 = defaultdict(faker.ISS_USER_NAME)

    # Iterate over the rows and yield anonymized rows.
    for row in rows:
        # Replace the name and email fields with faked fields.
        row['CARD_NO_ID']  = c1[row['CARD_NO_ID']]
        row['ISS_USER_NAME'] = c2[row['ISS_USER_NAME']]

        # Yield the row back to the caller
        yield row

    """
    The source argument is a path to a CSV file containing data to 
    anonymize, while target is a path to write the anonymized CSV data to.
    """

source = 'card_transaction_data_all.csv'
target = 'card_transaction_data_all_fake.csv'

with open(source, 'rU') as f:
    with open(target, 'w') as o:
    # Use the DictReader to easily extract fields
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(o, reader.fieldnames)
        # Read and anonymize data, writing to target file.
        for row in anonymize_rows(reader):
            writer.writerow(row)
```

But I keep getting error as follows:

C:\Anaconda3.4\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\start_ipython_kernel.py:1: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 5, in 
    writer = csv.DictWriter(o, reader.fieldnames)

File "C:\Anaconda3.4\lib\csv.py", line 96, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)

File "C:\Anaconda3.4\lib\site-packages\unicodecsv\py3.py", line 55, in **next**
    return self.reader.**next**()

File "C:\Anaconda3.4\lib\site-packages\unicodecsv\py3.py", line 51, in 
    f = (bs.decode(encoding, errors=errors) for bs in f)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Can someone please help me implementing the code in Python 3? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For Python3, use the standard csv (import csv) and remove the U in 'rU'

Answer (score 1):

Me too spent some time converting the python2 faker example found online into python3. Convertion below should work (Big thanks to [@AKhooli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48171391/5386903)'s answer!)

```
    import csv
    from faker import Faker
    from collections import defaultdict

    def anonymize_rows(rows):

    """
    Rows is an iterable of dictionaries that contain name and
    email fields that need to be anonymized.
    """
        # Load the faker and its providers
        faker  = Faker()

        # Create mappings of names & emails to faked names & emails.
        c1  = defaultdict(faker.msisdn)
        c2 = defaultdict(faker.name)

        # Iterate over the rows and yield anonymized rows.
        for row in rows:
            # Replace the name and email fields with faked fields.
            row['CARD_NO_ID']  = c1[row['CARD_NO_ID']]
            row['ISS_USER_NAME'] = c2[row['ISS_USER_NAME']]

            # Yield the row back to the caller
            yield row

        """
        The source argument is a path to a CSV file containing data to 
        anonymize, while target is a path to write the anonymized CSV data to.
        """

    source = 'card_transaction_data_all.csv'
    target = 'card_transaction_data_all_fake.csv'

    with open(source, 'r') as f:
        with open(target, 'w', newline='') as o:
        # Use the DictReader to easily extract fields
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            writer = csv.DictWriter(o, reader.fieldnames)
            # Read and anonymize data, writing to target file
            # with header!
            writer.writeheader()
            for row in anonymize_rows(reader):
                writer.writerow(row)
```